# Get Posts shortcode plugin and meta_query?

Tags: shortcode, meta-query

I'm using [Get Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nurelm-get-posts/) plugin to list posts with post type "project". I want to filter the list by two custom fields: year (ex. 2006) and state (ex. Completed). I added `meta_query` to the plugin's `get_post` args and tried the shortcode:

```
[get_posts post_type="project" meta_query="array(array('key' => 'state', 'value' => 
'Completed'),array('key' => 'year','value' => '2006'))" suppress_filters="false"]
```

This is not working, though I can get both "state" and "year" to work by their own using `meta_key` and `meta_value`.

Can someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the plugin not being updated, this will not work because the meta_query arg is evaluated as a string:

```
array(3) {
  ["post_type"] => string(7) "project"
  ["meta_query"] => string(96) "array(array('key' => 'state', 'value' => 
'Completed'),array('key' => 'year','value' => '2006'))"
  ["suppress_filters"] => string(5) "false"
}
```

I suggest you make a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), where you would directly call get_posts() with the meta_query you want.

You will have to copy the code that handles the actual listing of the posts.

Comment: Thank you. I moved to the template solution. I'm now struggling with it over here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15114/list-posts-under-meta-value-heading

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the plugin been updated to support the new query args, or specifically in this case, the `meta_query` arg.

The plugin page lists compatibility upto **3.0.5**, and if i remember correctly, `meta_query` was introduced in **3.1**, so naturally i'd conclude support is not yet available..

I could be wrong, just connecting the dots..

Answer (score 0):

The plugin uses `shortcode_atts` to limit the list of accepted arguments:

http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/nurelm-get-posts/tags/0.3/get-posts.php#L29

`meta_query` is not on that list. I'd suggest forking the plugin or asking the author to update it to allow meta queries.

Comment: Thank you. So, if `get_posts()` does not support `meta_query`, i'll need a `WP_Query()` or `query_posts()` shortcode plugin of some sort? Will they behave properly as a shortcode within a page, i.e. not in a template? Am I asking the right questions? What is, after all, the right way to get a filtered list by two custom fields?

Comment: get_posts() is just a wrapper for WP_Query, so meta_query does work, as well as any other arg that WP_Query can handle.

Comment: The second part about `get_posts()` not accepting `meta_query` is not correct, but the first part about it filtering attributes via `shortcode_atts()` is. I modified this answer to reflect this, but I leave it up to @John to do a complete edit.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake. I was mistaken about how `wp_parse_args()` worked.